# Modify url of an XMLHttpRequest object

Tags: jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest

As a fix for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1597396/jquery-ajax-call-to-url-containing-accent-character-sends-bad-uri-from-ie-to-serv) issue, I was wondering if anyone knows of a way to modify the URL of an XMLHttpRequest object prior to sending it.

Ideally, I want to change the uri (encode it) in the `beforeSend` event (using jQuery [$.ajaxSetup](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.ajaxSetup)) instead of changing it in every location where I'm using $.ajax

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

According to [the documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.ajax#toptions), the `beforeSend()` method is passed the `XMLHttpRequest` object as a parameter, and its `this` pointer is set to the Ajax request options. The `XMLHttpRequest` doesn't have an attribute that is the URL, but the [W3C documentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#the-open-method) seems to say that the object's `open()` method can be called multiple times on a given instance:

```
beforeSend: function(xhr) {
    // if you're doing authenticated requests, you might have to
    // call the 5-argument form of open() instead
    xhr.open(this.type, this.url.replace( /* whatever with whatever... */ ), this.async);
  }
```

One potential issue with doing this is that calling `open()` clears all of the request headers that have been set, so you may have to add some additional code in there to re-add the headers that jQuery sets before invoking `beforeSend()`.

**EDIT:** Sure enough. Now that I've taken a look at the [jQuery source](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js), you're right: the URL is set before the `beforeSend()` method is invoked. Hopefully the revisions above will work for you.

Comment: That's what I tried first, but the XMLHttpRequest object has already been constructed by this time and so editing the url in the request options doesn't work. I need to edit the 'xhr' instance passed in.